# How to return void in JsDoc?

Tags: javascript, ide, jsdoc

Is there a specified way to declare a method or a function to return void in JsDoc? Currently I am in the belief that `void` is the default return value, and other return values must be specifically provided:

```
/**
 * @return {Integer} The identifier for ...
 */
```

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/valid-jsdoc says `@returns {void}` Ahhh someone already mentioned it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45450508/470749

Answer (score 119, accepted):

I don't believe you have to choose from a set of types in JsDoc... you can use any type name you wish (the curly braces indicate it's a type), so you can simply do:

```
@return {void}
```

Although, this is probably more correct for JavaScript:

```
@return {undefined}
```

Comment: may be also `@returns {void}` ?

Comment: What about returning `null`?

Comment: @Eugene `null` is not necessarily the same as `undefined`

Comment: `@return {Void}` throws code inspection warning in IntelliJ IDE `@return {undefined}` and `@return {void}` does not.

Comment: `null` is never the same as `undefined`. When something is null, it is still defined but with no value. Undefined is, well, not defined :-)

Comment: The Ecmascript specifications list the language's types. The value returned by the `void` operator is `undefined`. The name of the type of the value `undefined` is `Undefined`, even though `typeof undefined` evaluates to `"undefined"`. The name `Void` is not defined in Ecmascript specifications.

Comment: eslint.org/docs/rules/valid-jsdoc - per the answer below should be `@returns {void}` not `{Void}` and not `{undefined}`. since this is top + accepted answer, would you consider editing?

Answer (score 126):

## Closure Compiler

According to the documentation of Google's Closure Compiler if nothing is being returned, the @return annotation should be omitted.

> If there is no return value, do not use a @return tag.

**Source:** https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/js-for-compiler#tags

## jsdoc-toolkit

However further documentation also states that the returnType and returnDescription are optional parameters.

> returnType - Optional: the type of the return value.
>
> returnDescription - Optional: any additional description.

**Source:** https://code.google.com/p/jsdoc-toolkit/wiki/TagReturns

## Summary

You could either leave out the return annotation or include it without any parameters.

Comment: This answer is actually better than the accepted one. If your function doesn't return a result, you shouldn't say it returns ``undefined`` as this is already implicit in Javascript and may cause confusion to whoever reads your docs.

Comment: No, I disagree and say this is not a good idea. When something is missing you don't know if it was intentional or not. By being explicit about the return type even when it's `undefined` you force yourself to state your intent, also good when reading it later. Just to clarify, I'm not saying one should include a useless JS statement, I'm saying one should always include a JSDoc `@returns` statement (I'm against useless code, but not against "useless" comments).

Comment: IMO it makes sense to specify a return type of undefined if it is possible that your function or method returns any other value, in which case you get something like this: `@returns {Array|undefined} - returns array if operation successful, otherwise returns undefined`

Comment: I know it's not Python, but "explicit is better than implicit"

Comment: `eslint-plugin-jsdoc` gets unhappy if you leave out a `@returns {void}`

Answer (score 30):

Looking at the ESlint docs they use
`@returns {void}`

Source: http://eslint.org/docs/rules/valid-jsdoc

Since I need to provide an `@returns` for each function to pass tests in order to push code for certain projects this is required in my case.

Answer (score 1):

To help to decide between the other answers, there is one benefit in explicitly written `@return {void}`. Although `@return` can be omitted, for a documenting coder, seeing the `@return {void}` works as a memory aid. It tells the coder that the return documentation is written. If there is no `@return` written, then the coder might need to inspect did he forget to write the return value documentation or does the function truly return nothing.

Of course, the return value documentation might be outdated. That is something the coder cannot directly know from the docs and needs to read the code to verify. Still, seeing the return value written gives the coder a bit of certainty that the documentation is correct and not just hastily written.

Answer (score 1):

I find this less ambiguous than leaving out the `@returns`:

```
@returns {} Nothing is returned.
```

or even

```
@returns {} Nothing is returned because this is a broadcast receiver.
```

Just an idea.